# Ruby hash delete_if many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Some_hash.delete_if {|key, value| key == "at" || key == "with" || key == "from"}
```

I just included 3 ors but I have a list of 7 and this line becomes very long and ugly. Is there a way to do this in a shorter way without having to do `key == SOMEVALUE` every time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574162/simplifying-a-check-in-ruby

Comment: This answer doesn't use the handy except method included in Rails.

Comment: @Iceman Good point. I've voted to re-open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SomeHash.except(:key1, :key2, ...)
```

Rails comes with the handy [Hash#except](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) extension:

> Return a hash that includes everything but the given keys.

Comment: Note that `#except` returns a duplicate hash with the keys removed, see `#except!` for the in-place mutator.

Answer (score 3):

```
%w[at with from]
.each_with_object(Some_hash){|k, h| h.delete(k)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
keys_to_remove = ['at', 'with', 'from']
hash.delete_if {|key,_| keys_to_remove.include? key}
```

Comment: ended up going with this although @iceman's answer is the best!